# keep a remote repository up to date without the entire history

Tags: git

We have the situtation that we need split our codebase with a 3th party and we cant give them our history and delete some stuff, but we do need to keep the remote repository up to date with new commits that happen after the cutoff. Basically we want only forward history on top of the deletions.

I think I want to be able to keep a branch in the source reposistory (that contains the deletions) (`source/clean`  up to date with the master of the source (this can be done by regularly merging master into that branch), And have a remote repository who's history begins after `source/clean`  has committed the deletes. (`target/main`)

What seems to be working somewhat is to cherry pick the commits from `source/clean` to `target/main`. However i like to automate this proccess and cherry picking all commits by hand is  not an option.

I can give a range to cherry-pick but that gets messed up by the merge-commits on the `source/clean` branch.

something like:

```
Source/main - A - B - C - ------------ D - E ------- F - G
source/clean            \ deletions --------- \ D  -- E merge ----\ F - G - merge
target/main                         \initial copy \D'\ \E'          \F'  \G'
```

Does anyone know a way to cleanly do something like this in a way that can be automated?

Comment: Give them a shallow (one-deep) single-branch clone of your repository. That way, the only thing they see at the outset is one commit, and each time they `fetch` they get only new commits on that branch going forward.

Comment: However, I have to add that what you're asking to do is opposed to the spirit of Git so there isn't likely to be a hard-as-nails way to implement it.